# Viewport vs Percentage

Tags: html, css

I am always using percentage when creating responsive designs and I haven't used viewports yet.
I just like to know when to use viewport and when to use percentage because it looks similar for me.

#### [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ske3s/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="percent">Hello World</div>
<br/>
<div class="viewport">Hello World</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.percent{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#09c;
    color:white;
}
div.viewport{
    width:100vw;
    background-color:#09c;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Percentages are often based on parent containers, viewport units are always consistent with the viewport.

If you have a percentage on a direct child of `body` then they're already off, since body has a default margin.

Answer (score 0):

Viewport units are used only on font sizes, unless the specs for them have changed since I last checked.

Percentages can be used (almost) anywhere, and are relative to the last set parent container, taking into account paddings and margins.

However, viewport unitss can be used in place of percentages in combination with `rem` and `em`. I've done this a few times, but I don't recommend it for fluid designs. The idea is you set the font of `html` to `1vw` or `1vh` (depends on what you want), then use `rem` units througout. If you set the root as `1vw`, then `1rem` would be equal to `1%` of the vieport width.